Предлог ОТ в сочетаниях с дробями

Из недавней темы:

60% количества картофеля, собранного со второго участка. Предлога ОТ нет.
Помогите понять: 2/3 — это от 68 тонн, или 2/3 — от второго участка? Предлог ОТ используется.

А как сделать правильный выбор, от чего это зависит?

Розенталь. Управление в русском языке (названы оба варианта):
ЧАСТЬ чего / от чего. Часть дачи сдавалась внаём; Часть от этого дохода пойдёт на благотворительные цели.

Тема обсуждалась на форуме дважды, но непонятно, откуда отвечающие  брали информацию, ведь ссылок нет, хотя ответы очень уверенные.  Обязательные ссылки стали давать уже позднее, раньше не считали нужным))

Вот одно из мнений:
Современная норма требует использования при управлении словами "часть", "половина", "треть", "доля" и т.п. беспредложного родительного падежа. Ранее в этих (и некоторых других, весьма далеких от темы) случаях использовался родительный с "предлогом от".
Хотелось бы увидеть эту норму, но где ее найти?
Тема 1. 1/2 от чего-то или чего-то?
Тема 2  50 процентов (от) стоимости" Нужен ли предлог "от"?

Ну вы же сами дали ответ на этот вопрос.

Спасибо, Серж, но мне бы ссылку хотелось: Розенталь, Грамота или хотя бы что-то.  В однотомной грамматике 1990 года (Шведова, Лопатин) нормируется беспредложное управление Р.п. для количественно-разделительных отношений: глоток воды, литр молока и т.д.  Процент туда подходит. Предложное управление называется "отторгнутая принадлежность": скорлупа от ореха, крышка от чайника.  Если только это))

Ну там, по-моему, Людмила приводила ссылку.
